# ATmega 8 wrong timing with Arduino NG bootloader

Tags: isp, frequency

I have build simple Arduino ISP programmer, which works fine on ATmega 328 chips (when I select Arduino UNO board) and a ton of others (tiny45, tiny2313). But, when I want to program an ATmega8 chip, it writes it succesfuly, but then the chip runs at 1/16 of the desired speed! (for example a delay(1000) in code takes 16 seconds real-life). I have a 16 MHz crystal oscillator with capacitors connected to the chip, so I thought that the problem is not there but... when I remove the crystal, the chip still runs the same, it still takes 16 seconds.
So I assume two possibilities:

1. the crystal is somehow broken, so the chip runs from some internal
   thing? But I tried multiple crystals, all the same,

OR

2. I am doing something wrong, but I really don't know what...

Does somebody have an idea what may be wrong or how to test it? Or feel free for more details...Thanks

EDIT: In IDE, I am selecting "Arduino NG or older" and then I select ATmega8  as processor. I am uploading the sketches directly, without bootloader.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the fuse bit configuration - specifically, that you are running with an internal oscillator and with a divider configuration that gives you a 1 MHz clock rate.

Comment: Second the fuse bits. Try selecting `burn bootloader` in the arduino menu, as that should set the correct fuses.

Comment: I checked it, and in boards.txt, my fuses are set to 0xDF (low) and 0xCA, which, according to this (http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc) should set to external crystal. I even tried to change low to 0x4C, which should run it at 8MHz internally, but it had no effect...

Comment: Gerben: Avrdude returns: "efuse" memory type not defined for part "ATmega8"... I dont know what an efuse is...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally solved it, so I will write it here so somebody may learn from it in the future :) The problem was really in the fuses, thanks Chris Stratton. Most of my chips were bought already modified for working with Arduino. But this ATmega 8 had the factory fuses, which were setting it for working with internal 1MHz oscillator. You can read and your write your fuse settings with avrdude, so I set them to arduino default (lfuse 0xDF, hfuse 0xCA, from boards.txt). Now it works perfectly even without uploading bootloader.